# What is Python equivalent of for(i=1;i<10000000;i=1*10)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In python how can we create a for-loop that does not have a constant step-size? I want to create a for-loop with step-function i=i*10, How can I do that?

For example: I want to create a python equivalent for: `for(i=1;i<10000000;i=i*10){...}`
How do I do this in python2 and python3?

I know that I can just use while-loop But I want to know if there is a way using for-loop?

Comment: `for(i=1;i<10000000;i=i*10){...}`. Almost same. Use `for i in range (1,10000000):  i = i*10 do some action here`

Comment: in the (top answers of the) duplicate there is no mention of the relation between the maximum of `i` and the maximal exponent...

Comment: @Yusufsn this will not reproduce the series that is requested here...

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant:

```
from math import log

for i in (10 ** e for e in range(round(log(10000000, 10)))):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, a C for loop is a syntactic sugar, where

```
for (init; cond; step)
  body
```

is equivalent to

```
init;
while (cond) {
  body;
  step;
}
```

which is, again trivially, translatable into Python:

```
i = 1
while i < 10000000:
    do_stuff(i)
    i *= 10
```

On the other hand, Python's for loop consumes an iterator. I can't think of an off-the-shelf iterator you could use, but if you create an iterator that has the property you desire, you can do so.

```
def geometric_range(start, end, step):
    i = start
    while i < end:
        yield i
        i *= step

for i in geometric_range(1, 10000000, 10):
    do_stuff(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a `while` loop:

```
i = 1
while i < 10000000:
    print(i)
    # the rest of your logic
    i = i*10
```

Comment: I did not want to use while loop

Comment: Why?  If it works, then what is the problem with a `while` loop?